# Enter own .htaccess rewrite rules in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to write a own rewrite rule into my htacces. The redirection itself works fine but Wordpress validates the URI with `$_SERVER["REQUIRE_URI"]`. So the site Title is Changed automatically to page not found, the loop doesn't works and so on.

Is there anyway to do this?

If not is there a other possibility actually I only need a really simple redirect from `"www.example.com/test/"` to `"www.example.com/t.php?a=1`" So it's completely static i don't need patterns at all. I have already tried it with "frameset" but that looks pretty ugly and makes the process slow.

Thank you very much

Jakob

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# My Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Malta/$ http://www.reisekontrast.de/Index?malta=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^China/$ http://www.reisekontrast.de/Index?china=1  [QSA,L]


# WP Rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code currently in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

We need your original .htaccess file. This is an easy rewrite (redirect), but wordpress already has URL Rewriting rules. To help you best would mean we need to work cohesively with what settings you already have running. Otherwise your are just going to break Wordpress but get your URL's working.

Also, as a primer question, does your server support full override in htaccess?

Based on your HTACCESS file, I would add the section for "Custom" Rules. That way it bypasses the Rewrite Conditions that are arbitrary in this type of rewrite.

Hope this helps! Let me know if I can provide more detail or other options.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Custom rules
RewriteRule /test/(.*) http://example.com/t.php?a=1 [NC]

# My Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Malta/$ http://www.reisekontrast.de/Index?malta=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^China/$ http://www.reisekontrast.de/Index?china=1  [QSA,L]


# WP Rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I posted my htaccess file.

Comment: I hope you don't think that was me. I signed up today i can't vote anyway.

Comment: I added this line: RewriteRule /test/(.*) http://example.com/t.php?a=1 [NC] Give it a try and see if that helps.

Comment: @Tait Your original answer was not an answer, it was a request for more information and a question. This kind of thing will attract downvotes and (possibly) flags on SO. I would suspect this was the reason for the downvote you got. Please avoid asking a question in an answer and use a comment instead, when you have enough reputation.